# CodeIgniter flashdata cyrillic error

Tags: php, codeigniter

My database.table ci_sessions is utf8_general_ci, in my .htaccess i've set

```
addDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

in my config file:

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

but if i write a cyrillic character in my flash session data, all my sessions get destroyed and i am logging out automatically, how to fix this problem?

my file is utf-8 without bom, but if i write inside

```
$message = 'ВЦФАФАП';
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
            redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

sessions destroyed...

Comment: just solved, i've set session.user_database = FALSE, and that worked, looks like that the whole database was set in latin charset, rather than utf8, ignoring the table utf-8 charset, thanks all)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, but my session was not stored in the database to begin with.
My charset was also set to UTF-8.

My solution to this problem is to make sure that the encoding of the file is set to UTF-8 also. How to do this depends on which editor you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try add  base64_encode()  function. For insert DB `base64_encode(serialize($session_data))`. For select `unserialize(base64_decode($db_data))`.